# Where can I find resources to find user-contributed GPS tracks?

Tags: preparation, gps

For trip planning and navigation during my outdoors trip, I would like to load a track into my GPS (or GNSS) receiver.  Where can I find websites that gather user-contributed GPS tracks?

Answer (score 6):

Different sites are strong in different parts of the world or for different activities, even if most aim to cover all activities.  This is a list of such websites.

This is a community wiki effort.  Please [**edit this answer**](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/posts/24728/edit) to add other sites you are aware of.

### Global, all activities

- [Alltrails](https://www.alltrails.com/) (formerly also Everytrail, GPSies, and possibly other sites).  American company based in San Francisco.  Popular in North America.   Freemium model.
- [Openstreetmap traces](https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces) (I don't know if there is any easy way to browse them).  Completely free (both gratis and libre).
- [Trailforks](https://www.trailforks.com).  Focus on mountain biking, but also includes other activities (albeit only 20k hiking trails worldwide).
- [Viewranger](https://my.viewranger.com) (free account required)
- [Wikiloc](https://www.wikiloc.com/).  Spanish/Catalonian company, popular in Europe, very popular in Spain.  Freemium model.

**Alltrails vs. Wikiloc?**

It appears that in North America, Alltrails is more popular than Wikiloc, in southern Europe, Wikiloc is more popular than Alltrails, and elsewhere they might be similar:

- Waterton Lakes National Park (Canada): Alltrails has 131 hiking trails 
  including [56 from Waterton Park](https://www.alltrails.com/explore?cc=true&b_tl_lat=49.0581762474862&b_tl_lng=-113.93296480178832&b_br_lat=49.04276294851421&b_br_lng=-113.88633728027344),  Wikiloc has [18 from Waterton Park](https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/map.do?lt=49.0499&ln=-113.9088&z=16&k=1&event=map&act=1).
- In Theodore Roosevelt National Park (USA, North Unit), Alltrails has 17, Wikiloc has 1.
- In Parque Nacional de Ordesa y Monte Perdido (Spain), Wikiloc contains ~25k hiking tracks, including [5,280 from one popular trailhead](https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/map.do?lt=42.6491&ln=-0.0582&z=18&k=1&event=map&act=1).  AllTrails contains ~250 in the park and [74 from the same trailhead](https://www.alltrails.com/explore?cc=true&b_tl_lat=42.65174341546969&b_tl_lng=-0.06541907787322998&b_br_lat=42.647419050080316&b_br_lng=-0.053762197494506836).
- From Kvikkjokk, Sweden, AllTrails has 29, Wikiloc has 24.
- I checked some parks in Namibia and South Korea where they were also in balance in popularity.

### Regional or special purpose

- Cycling, worldwide: [Bikemap.net](https://www.bikemap.net/)
- Walking, Scotland: [Walkhighlands](https://www.walkhighlands.co.uk/Forum/find-a-walk.php) (Scottish walks, not just Highlands but all over Scotland)

Comment: Do any of these forward-feed curated info into generalized Creative-Commons or Open Data licensed databases like Open Street Map (which is weak on trails)?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I'm only familiar with Wikiloc, which does not automatically have a open license.  I think copyright stays with the original user by default.  There are tracklogs on Openstreetmap too, called [traces](https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces), but I don't know if there is a good platform to browse them.